# Responsive footer html

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, footer

I made a footer with html, css and bootstrap and it's responsive to some kind of exctent but when it gets to mobile size instead of the images being in a row they stack up and gets in a column, how can i fix this? I want i to be the same when it comes down to mobile size as it is when it is in desktop size. I hope you understand, sorry for my bad english. Here is the html:

```css
  /*Facebook*/

.fb-icon img {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}


/*Twitter*/

.twitter-icon img {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}


/*Mail*/

.mail-icon img {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 120px;
  width: 30%;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  /*Facebook*/
  .fb-icon img {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 5px;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<footer class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <!-- Facebook -->
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
      <a target="_blank" class="fb-icon" href="https://www.facebook.com/OxybinTravel"><img onmouseover="this.src='Travel/facebook-2-color.png'" onmouseout="this.src='Travel/facebook-2.png'" alt="Facebook icon" src="Travel/facebook-2.png"></a>
    </div>
    <!-- Twitter -->
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
      <a target="_blank" class="twitter-icon" href="https://twitter.com/oxybintravel"><img onmouseover="this.src='Travel/p-color.png'" onmouseout="this.src='Travel/p.png'" alt="Twitter icon" src="Travel/p.png"></a>
    </div>
    <!-- Mail -->
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
      <div class="tool-tip">
        <a target="_blank" class="mail-icon" href="#"><img onmouseover="this.src='Travel/email-color.png'" onmouseout="this.src='Travel/email.png'" alt="Mail icon" src="Travel/email.png"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, if you check your bootstrap you will see that bootstrap is using `col-sm-4` on mobile devices and has a `max-width: 100%` css property. Just add this css snipped into your `media query`

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  /*Facebook*/

  .col-sm-4 {
    max-width:33.3%;
    display:inline-block;
  }
....
}
```

Comment: That worked but now they go in to each other and overlap eachother

Comment: @Linus The `col-sm-4` is overriting the `col-xs-4` so if you want to to have on small devices `col-4` the best way for you would be to remove entirely the `col-sm-4` you don't need it, the code will work perfectly with only `col-xs-4` .  Like that ` <div class="col-xs-4">`

Comment: use `col-xs-4` instead of `col-sm-4` you don't need both

Comment: @Linus what version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: Try changing the css for the images to the same css for  the img-responsive class from bootstrap

Comment: I am using bootstrap 4

Comment: do you want them to stack when the reach a certain size?  The only other solution is to make the images smaller when it reaches a certain size.

Comment: @Linus the only solution is to use col-xs-4 on elements, other than that it won't work or use the media query I posted above. Please inspect your element and you will see that `col-sm-4` has priority over `col-xs-4` thus making everything 100% or you can limit `col-sm-4` to a `max-width` in media query, if it's smaller than 600 px make it 33.3%